# Adding subtitles to AVPlayer video

Tags: swift, avplayer, avasset, avqueueplayer, closed-captions

I am using an `AVPlayerView` to display some local videos from my Apps Bundle directory. Now I want to add the ability to display subtitles for increased accessibility of my content.

Since I’m the programmer, filmmaker as well as the one who has to create the subtitles, I am open to any subtitle-formats & solutions. I discovered a few common formats (`.srt`, `.scc`), but however, I am wondering how to work with them "programmatically" using `AVPlayer`.

I initialize videos like:

```
let myVideoPlayer = AVQueuePlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/myPath"))
```

If you play subtitled videos in QuickTime for example, it is enough to have both files (subtitles & video) in the same directory. I couldn’t find any hints or solutions like adding a subtitle-file-url to the `AVPlayer`, which I would expect. **It seems that’s not the right approach?**

[Other threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312118/show-subtitles-with-an-avfoundation-avplayer-on-os-x) mention that AVPlayers `closedCaptionDisplayEnabled` works well with `Closed Caption` tracks. But again that brings me to the question: **How can I display subtitles with AVPlayer from a separate file (like .srt, .scc)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following workaround: Exporting my material from `Final Cut Pro X` as .m4v, creating subtitles manually with `SRT Edit Pro` and then adding them to the videofile with `Subler`, so I have just one file in the end. This way AVPlayer / QuickTime automatically detects the subtitle-track.

Answer (score 2):

I used **ixany**'s suggestion (add subtitles to video file), but then I had to force AVPlayer to display subtitles using this code:

```
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
if let group = playerItem.asset.mediaSelectionGroup(forMediaCharacteristic: .legible) {
    let locale = Locale(identifier: "en-EN")
    let options = AVMediaSelectionGroup.mediaSelectionOptions(from: group.options, with: locale)
    if let option = options.first {
        playerItem.select(option, in: group)
    }
}
```

And beware of testing this in **simulator**. For me this works only on real device.

Answer (score -1):

This is perfect answer for adding close caption in AVPlayer. Need to just paste this code in your code.
Thanks

```
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
if let group = playerItem.asset.mediaSelectionGroup(forMediaCharacteristic: .legible) {
    let locale = Locale(identifier: "en")
    let options = AVMediaSelectionGroup.mediaSelectionOptions(from: group.options, with: locale)
    if let option = options.first {
        playerItem.select(option, in: group)
    }
}
```

Comment: This has already been mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51419873/2227743). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*

Comment: Yes i agree with you but i just uploaded this to confirmed for perfect match. Nothing else @EricAya

Comment: I apologies for that I have one question. Could i ask you?